# How to get Wikidata labels in more than one language?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm traying to get the regions of Italy in both Italian and English. I can get then in one laguage with this query...

```
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?RegionIT ?RegionITLabel ?ISO_code ?Geo
{
?RegionIT wdt:P31 wd:Q16110;
wdt:P300 ?ISO_code; 
wdt:P625 ?Geo 
           SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "it"  }
}

ORDER BY ?regionITLabel
```

... but adding another language using the standard SPARQL syntax doesn't work.

Comment: Multiple labels using the label service: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49118702/sparql-querying-wikidata-labels-for-more-than-one-language

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ... but adding another language using the standard SPARQL syntax doesn't work.

How are you doing that? This works:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?RegionIT ?label (lang(?label) as ?label_lang)  ?ISO_code ?Geo
{
    ?RegionIT wdt:P31 wd:Q16110;
              wdt:P300 ?ISO_code; 
              wdt:P625 ?Geo ;
              rdfs:label ?label
}
order by ?RegionIT
```

[Link to try query](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX%20wikibase%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3FRegionIT%20%3Flabel%20%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%20as%20%3Flabel_lang%29%20%3FISO_code%20%3FGeo%0A%7B%0A%3FRegionIT%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ16110%3B%0Awdt%3AP300%20%3FISO_code%3B%20%0Awdt%3AP625%20%3FGeo%20%3B%0Ardfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%0A%7D%0Aorder%20by%20%3FRegionIT)

To limit to just Italian and English filter on the lang:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?RegionIT ?label ?ISO_code ?Geo
{
    ?RegionIT wdt:P31 wd:Q16110;
              wdt:P300 ?ISO_code; 
              wdt:P625 ?Geo ;
              rdfs:label ?label
    filter(lang(?label) = 'it' || lang(?label) = 'en')
}
order by ?RegionIT
```

[Link to try query](https://query.wikidata.org/#%20PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20wikibase%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3FRegionIT%20%3Flabel%20%3FISO_code%20%3FGeo%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FRegionIT%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ16110%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP300%20%3FISO_code%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP625%20%3FGeo%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20filter%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%27it%27%20%7C%7C%20lang%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20order%20by%20%3FRegionIT)

Obviously that multiplies the number of results, one for each language. If that's an issue you can do:

```
...
rdfs:label ?label_it , ?label_en
filter(lang(?label_it) = 'it' && lang(?label_en) = 'en')
...
```

which is effectively what the language service does.

Comment: Thanks. This indeed answers the question. My intention was to learn how to achieve it with `SERVICE wikibase:label` but that wasn't clear from the question. Yet, I'd appreciate any ideas about that.

Comment: you can request several languages with `SERVICE wikibase:label` like so: `SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "it,en"  }`, but it's only a fallback mechanism, you will only get the first defined label from the requested languages, not one label per language.

Answer (score 10):

Let's list all countries in English and Russian.

```
#List of countries in English and Russian
SELECT ?country ?label_en ?label_ru
WHERE
{
    ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256.
    ?country rdfs:label ?label_en filter (lang(?label_en) = "en").
    ?country rdfs:label ?label_ru filter (lang(?label_ru) = "ru").
}
```

[SPARQL query](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23List%20of%20countries%20in%20English%20and%20Russian%0ASELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3Flabel_en%20%3Flabel_ru%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ6256.%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel_en%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Flabel_en%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29.%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel_ru%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Flabel_ru%29%20%3D%20%22ru%22%29.%0A%7D)

This example was taken from the tutorial [Research in programming Wikidata](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Research_in_programming_Wikidata/Countries#List_of_countries), section "Countries".

Comment: This is what I exactly wanted. Thanks for the quick demo.