# SPARQL: Querying Wikidata labels for more than one language

Tags: sparql, wikidata, blazegraph

I am trying to get labels in multiple languages from Wikidata's SPARQL endpoint.  The following example is given [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/SERVICE_-_Label):

```sparql
SELECT ?country ?country_EN ?country_DE ?country_FR
   WHERE {
     ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q185441. # member state of the European Union
     SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
            ?country rdfs:label ?country_EN.
     }
     SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "de".
            ?country rdfs:label ?country_DE.
     }
     SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr".
            ?country rdfs:label ?country_FR.
     }
}
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3Fcountry_EN%20%3Fcountry_DE%20%3Fcountry_FR%0A%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ185441.%20%23%20member%20state%20of%20the%20European%20Union%0A%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_EN.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22de%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_DE.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22fr%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_FR.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

However, this returns the following error:

> Unknown error: there can be only one "run last" join in any group

Is there a solution to get labels in more than one language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rdfs:label` can be used directly without the `wikibase:label` service:

```sparql
SELECT ?country ?country_en ?country_de ?country_fr
   WHERE {
     ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q185441. # member state of the European Union
     OPTIONAL {?country rdfs:label ?country_en filter (lang(?country_en) = "en")}.
     OPTIONAL {?country rdfs:label ?country_de filter (lang(?country_de) = "de")}.
     OPTIONAL {?country rdfs:label ?country_fr filter (lang(?country_fr) = "fr")}.
}
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3Fcountry_en%20%3Fcountry_de%20%3Fcountry_fr%0A%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ185441.%20%23%20member%20state%20of%20the%20European%20Union%0A%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_en%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Fcountry_en%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%7D.%0A%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_de%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Fcountry_de%29%20%3D%20%22de%22%29%7D.%0A%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_fr%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Fcountry_fr%29%20%3D%20%22fr%22%29%7D.%0A%7D)

Comment: FYI, this doesn't provide Q-id fallbacks.

Comment: What is "Q-id fallback"?

Comment: For example, Lithuanian label for [Q29999](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q29999) is missing. The label service would return `"Q29999"`.

Comment: SPARQL 1.1 `COALESCE`

Answer (score 6):

The label service optimizer [adds](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/WDQR/change/master/blazegraph/src/main/java/org/wikidata/query/rdf/blazegraph/label/LabelServicePlacementOptimizer.java;916cd2265ccec2c724c8d552923949e1543e4b53) a `hint:Prior hint:runLast true` [hint](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/QueryHints) to the label service unless there’s another explicit hint:

```java
LabelServiceUtils.getLabelServiceNodes(op).forEach(service -> {
    if (service.getProperty(QueryHints.RUN_LAST)  != null ||
        service.getProperty(QueryHints.RUN_FIRST) != null) {
        return;
    }
    service.setProperty(QueryHints.RUN_LAST, TRUE);
});
```

One should just add `hint:Prior hint:runLast false` to all the label service invocations after the first one.

Your query should be:

```sql
SELECT ?country ?country_EN ?country_DE ?country_FR
   WHERE {
     ?country wdt:P463 wd:Q458. # member state of the European Union
     SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
            ?country rdfs:label ?country_EN.
     }
     SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "de".
            ?country rdfs:label ?country_DE.
     } hint:Prior hint:runLast false.
     SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr".
            ?country rdfs:label ?country_FR.
     } hint:Prior hint:runLast false.
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3Fcountry_EN%20%3Fcountry_DE%20%3Fcountry_FR%0A%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP463%20wd%3AQ458.%20%23%20member%20state%20of%20the%20European%20Union%0A%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_EN.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22de%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_DE.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20hint%3APrior%20hint%3ArunLast%20false.%0A%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22fr%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_FR.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20hint%3APrior%20hint%3ArunLast%20false.%0A%7D)

Obviously, it is possible to fetch labels in multiple languages using regular SPARQL, and this is less verbose. However the label service provides language fallbacks, including the final one to Q-id's.

Source:

- https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T175840