# Retrieving all items that are instances or sub-instances or sub-sub-instances in a chain

Tags: query-optimization, sparql, wikidata

I need a logic `OR` of all valid statements about an item or its parents (instance-parent or subclass-parent).

Example: `Q957653` is a instance of `Q3184121`, and the last have `?item P17 Q155`. So  safisfies a chain  `Q957653 P31 Q3184121 P17 Q155`... So I need something  as

```
    ?item P17 Q155
    | ?item P31 ?x P17 Q155
    | ?item P31 ?x P31 ?y P17 Q155
    | ?item P279 ?x P17 Q155
    | ?item P279 ?x P31 ?y P17 Q155
    | ?item P279 ?x P279 ?y P17 Q155
```

A big logic "or"  for all possible chains of P31 or P279 dependences.

---

### Real example

I need a list of items that have some property (eg. `?item wdt:P402 _:b0.`) and are instances or subclasses of items with other property, eg. `wdt:P17 wd:Q155`.

The "first level" of `?item wdt:P17 wd:Q155` is working fine,

```sparql
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?osm_relid ?itemLabel 
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P402 _:b0.
  ?item wdt:P17 wd:Q155.
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P1448 ?name. }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P402 ?osm_relid .}
  SERVICE wikibase:label { 
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". 
  }
}
```

But how to express the *union* (or logic "or") of all other possible dependences?

### Edit/Notes

Supposing that `?item wdt:P31*/wdt:P279* wd:Qxx .`  will be all "chain dependences of something Qxx", as I need... But `Qxx`  is also a query,
 `?item wdt:P31*/wdt:P279* (?xx wdt:P17 wd:Q155) .`.

... **A solution (!) seems**

```
SELECT  (COUNT(DISTINCT ?item) AS ?count) 
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P402 _:b0.
  ?item  (wdt:P31*|wdt:P279*)/wdt:P17 wd:Q155 .
}
```

but I can't check because is time-consuming.

... Something perhaps near the "feasible solution" is
 `?item wdt:P31*/wdt:P279*/wdt:P31*/wdt:P17 wd:Q155 .` 

... after testing feasibles, seems `wdt:P31*/wdt:P279*/wdt:P17` the only "optimal" with no time-out problem.

Comment: SPARQL 1.1 property paths are the only way to implement this somehow, and you already figured out that those to not perform well in many situations. welcome to the limitations of SPARQL ... in the end, it's not a graph traversal language, thus, there are usually no index structures that would allow better performance for those kind of queries (imagine a graph with a very deep structure), thus, it has to perform joins as long as there are no edges along the path

Comment: `SELECT distinct ?item ?osm_relid
WHERE {
  ?item  (wdt:P31|wdt:P279)*/wdt:P17 wd:Q155 .
  ?item wdt:P402 ?osm_relid .
  hint:Prior hint:runLast true .
}` ~5600 results in ~10 seconds

Comment: @AKSW, thanks, I agree... But look Stanlislav's clues! there are a Bigdata initiative at  https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/QueryHints

Comment: @StanislavKralin, perfect, that **is the answer**!  PS: I changed P402 to P625, and it is running fast with ~32000 items.

Comment: @PeterKrauss yes, I saw this. something that is triple store specific and doesn't hold in general. In a perfect world, the query optimizer would do this automatically for us, but this will never happen indeed - there will be always corner cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to improve performance, you can use Blazegraph [query hints](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/QueryHints). Query hints allow to modify auto-generated query execution plan.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?osm_relid ?name {
  ?itemi wdt:P17 wd:Q155 .
  hint:Prior hint:runFirst true .
  ?item (wdt:P31|wdt:P279)* ?itemi .
  ?item wdt:P625 [].
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P1448 ?name. }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P402 ?osm_relid .}
  SERVICE wikibase:label { 
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". 
  }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fosm_relid%20%3Fname%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitemi%20wdt%3AP17%20wd%3AQ155%20.%0A%20%20hint%3APrior%20hint%3ArunFirst%20true%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%28wdt%3AP31%7Cwdt%3AP279%29%2a%20%3Fitemi%20.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP1448%20%3Fname.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP402%20%3Fosm_relid%20.%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%2C%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%22.%20%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

[This](https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?explain&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fosm_relid%20%3Fname%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitemi%20wdt%3AP17%20wd%3AQ155%20.%0A%20%20hint%3APrior%20hint%3ArunFirst%20true%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20(wdt%3AP31|wdt%3AP279)*%20%3Fitemi%20.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP1448%20%3Fname.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP402%20%3Fosm_relid%20.%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%2C[AUTO_LANGUAGE]%22.%20%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D) is how query execution plan looks like (just add `&explain` to the query URL and scroll down).

Please note that you [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49129274/7879193) use `hint:Prior hint:runLast true` from the original comment when the label service is used: there can be only one such hint in any graph pattern group.